# GIt pull command fails with cannot fork error in terminal

Tags: macos, git, terminal, bitbucket

Below is the detail description of the error occurred during the pull request.

```
error: cannot fork() for git-credential-osxkeychain: Resource temporarily unavailable 
remote: Counting objects: 56, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done. 
error: cannot fork() for unpack-objects: Resource temporarily unavailable 
fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off unpack-objects
```

Edit: After restarting the system it worked, still don't know why it occurred. I tried few git config stuffs but none worked.

Comment: I've faced this a few times as well. Try restarting your user session, and if that doesn't fix it, restarting your computer should certainly work.

Comment: `EAGAIN` from `fork` means that either the system as a whole has run out of processes, or the user has hit his or her process limit.  In a Terminal window, `limit` will show you your per-user `maxproc`.  `ps ux | wc -l` will approximate how many processes you are running.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Looked around in the interwebs. 
People with the same problem told me for them it was a temporary network availability problem.

Pulled again - problem was gone.
I was pulling locally on the server so this error maybe caused by temporarily missing resources on the server.